# Android load image from url and save to phone

Tags: android, image, url

Currently I have the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaLoc)), "image/" + type);
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

This was because the app used to download images from urls and saved them into the sdcard before viewing. But now I want to change the implementation to show the image from a url in the default image viewer when ACTION_VIEW is called and give them the option to save. Is this possible with ACTION_VIEW? I'm asking because I wish to use the default image viewer in the phone as it has already handled the zoom functions.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a custom action_view for it.